# A second order differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How does one solve the following differential equation

$y^{"}+xy^{'}+(1-x^2)y=y\sin x$?

I don't know how to proceed?

Comment: Tried it, got stuck solving the auxillary equation

Comment: $y^{"}+xy^{'}+(1-x^2)y=0$ is already a nightmare (to me at least).